# How to restore a group deleted with Remove-DistributionGroup cmdlet

Tags: azure, powershell, restore

I deleted a set of groups today that turns out people needed. HELP!

The ones I deleted manually I can recover with the
get-AzureADMSDeletedGroup cmdlet as the documentation says.

But I deleted a lot of groups using the Remove-DistributionGroup cmdlet and these do not appear in the above DeletedGroup cmdlet. How can I get these back?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like cmdlet deletions can't be restored. :-(
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/how-to-restore-a-group-deleted-with-remove/bea893c4-532d-4922-b4d0-5dc909eda9c9?rtAction=1659488104148